# Method to iterating through classes in a package using Reflection

Tags: java, eclipse, reflection, package

I am currently learning about Reflection and I have seen most of the similar posts to my question on stack however, I don't feel they fully answer my question on it.

I want to know if I have a package in Eclipse can I use Reflection to iterate through the classes in the package to find which one implements interface. There is only 1 interface so either they implement it or don't.

Could anyone provide a basic clear example as to how I may go about this? I have been told by some that this is just not possible whilst other people say it is possible using Reflection.

Thank you to any one who could help clear this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection API does not provide directly facility to iterate over classes in specific package. It concentrates on discovery of class once you have it.

To achieve what you want to have to read the class path of your application, iterate over the class path, open jars and go into directories, find files that end with `*.class` and get them as resource like `getResource(full_class_name)` or get it directly as class using `Class.forName()`.

This method has a limitation: you will not see classes loaded by custom class loaders.

Unless this is an exercise I'd recommend you to use [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library that does everything you need and (probably) even more... :)

Some more details

Java system property "java.class.path" contains class path of your application separated with `;` on Windows and `:` on Unix.

So, this is the way you can get list of class path elements:
`System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(File.pathSeparator)`

Here is some code sample that can help you to start:

```
for (String cpElement : System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(File.pathSeparator)) {
    File cpFile = new File(cpElement);
    if (!cpFile.exists()) {
         continue;
    }
    if (cpFile.isDirectory()) {
        findClassesInDirectory(cpFile);
    } else {
        findClassesInArchive(cpFile); 
    }
}
```

Etc, etc. I am leaving implementation of `findClassesInDirectory()` and `findClassesInArchive()` for you. Nice exercise. Have fun.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating more on this - 'iterate over the class path, open jars and go into directories' as to how I could go about this please? Thank you for your explanation too I have found it to be quite helpful,much appreciated :)

Comment: @user3373261, please see additions to my original answer.

Comment: Thank you for the extended comments and example code to help me get started! :)

Comment: When you mention find classes in archive - where would that be classed as?

Comment: I understand what findClassesInDirectory is for but what it findClassesInArchive used for? Hope I've made it a bit clearer : )

Answer (score 1):

have you heard of guava-libraries for Java.
They provide useful utilities regarding reflection.

For your specific problem, I would have a look a the `TypeToken` and the method `getTypes()`.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

yes you can so it. But with eclipse its more of an AST tree translation and not reflections. See if you want to iterate over source code and see which source file implements the interface you probably need AST tree walkers to do that. But on the other hand if you want to introspect at runtime the class files in a given package or a folder which implement the said interface then you need Reflections to do that. Either way its doable. I cant give you the code to try that out as a little time with Google will give you the answers you need though not all at the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection does not provide all operations for a total inspection.

For a *known* class one can get the physical URL of a class `SomeClass` using:

```
CodeSource codeSource = SomeClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
if (codeSource == null) {
    // Run-time class; URL into the rt.jar.
} else {
    URL url = codeSource.getLocation();
    // "file:/.... /classes/.../SomeClass.class"
    // "jar:file:/... /someJar.jar!/.../SomeClass.class"
}
```

For Java run time classes (rt.jar) codeSource will be null.
On the URL of the jar you can open a [(zip) file system](http://thinktibits.blogspot.de/2013/02/Java-NIO-ZIP-File-System-Provider-Example.html), and walk through folders as any real file system.

You'll probably want to inspect classes without `$` in the name (embedded, generated anonymous classes): only `fileName.matches("[^$]+\\.class")`.